# The grammar rules for the sentences with 'is', 'has' , and the switched position of object's adjective

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, adjectives, conjunctions

Regards.., i would like to discuss about the grammar of the sentences below, and whether they are dependent with their meanings.

> The pouring of the garden ***is*** a long tradition in the area and can be done ***to refresh the garden effectively***.
>
> The pouring of the garden ***is*** a long tradition in the area and can be done ***to effectively refresh the garden***.
>
> The pouring of the garden ***has*** a long tradition in the area and can be done ***to refresh the garden effectively***.

These 3 sentences looks logical and correct. 
..Thanks.

Comment: I haven't the least idea what "the pouring of the garden" might mean. But, assuming that it is the name of a tradition, it would not usually have "the" on the front.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what *pouring of the garden* is, your last sentence is best

> has a long tradition
>   is a long *held* tradition

is idiomatic

> to refresh the garden effectively

sidesteps the split infinitive in the second sentence.

Though all three sentences would usually be understood to have the same meaning.

Comment: The split infinitive version here (perhaps ungrammatically) can also mean "in effect", which results in a different meaning for the sentence:  "... to, in effect, refresh the garden."  This implies the garden is not truly being refreshed, but the effect is similar or the same. How do you know which meaning is intended? You have to go by context, and it may be ambiguous.